# Gauge graph with gradient green-yellow-red

Tags: css, highcharts

I am trying to achieve a gauge graph that will have a gradient based on the percentage it is full, similar to the image below. The closest I could manage is showing all the gradient colors regardless of the value - Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/64mfcg3v/4/).

```
    var x = 80; // Change x to see effects.
```

Did anyone managed to get a gradient based on value?

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D There a link to jsfiddle were it is coded

Comment: Apologies...missed that.

Comment: I think that you can use yAxis stops and small trick adding gradient to your chart. Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/64mfcg3v/6/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thank you! that's perfect

Comment: Happy to read my example worked for you. :) I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use yAxis stops and make small trick adding gradient to your chart. You can for example add points to your gauge (inside your load event callback function) with values decreasing from your normal y value to 0. It will give you a chance to have something similar to gradient with multiple points.

```
function(chart) {
    var y = this.series[0].data[0].y;
    for (var i = y; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
      chart.addSeries({
        data: [i],
        stickyTracking: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }, false)
    }
    chart.redraw();
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/64mfcg3v/6/

Kind regards,